# Exodus 28: 17-20 The usage of gems

Tags: exodus

This is the first time posting on here so sorry if I posted this wrong.

A few months back i finished reading Exodus. And I was very inspired by the usage of the Gems in the priest garments.

When I tried to look into the meaning of using these Gems, i came across alot of "spirtual crystal" sites and nothing really related to the Bible.

So i was wondering:
1. Was there any meaning behind using these specific gems?
2. Are these gems nowadays more "occult" related and should I just stay away from the gems?

I really don't know if these kind of questions are okay to ask on here but I hope y'all can help

Comment: Welcome to BH. I think your question may well have to be re-worded or it will be closed as off-topic. Your question does not actually appear to be about the text you are quoting. And your question is rather broad and extends beyond the concept of gems as applicable to scripture.

Comment: Have you already looked at this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemstones_in_the_Bible and if yes what further are you looking for?

Comment: @Autodidact I didn't come across this article thanks! This is actually what im looking for so Thanks alot for the quick response!

Comment: I took a look at the article which had a lot of great information, but I think the original question was more about the spiritual significance of the stones which was not addressed. This is a very fascinating question and one that could open up some interesting insights

Answer (score 1):

The 12 gems on the High Priest's breastplate, listed in Exodus 28:17-20, are given no significance in the text other than each stone represented a different tribe of Israel.  We are not even told which gem represented which tribe.  There has been much speculation on this since but it is just that.

However, what we do know is the significance such a breastplate had in subsequent literature, as the High Priest's breastplate became proverbial and metaphorical in apocalyptic writings:

- A similar list of gems appear in Ezekiel 28:13 about the taunt song about the King of Tyre (which some interpret as a veiled reference to Satan?), thus showing him as a possible false/counterfeit priest
- There is a reference to being adorned with precious stones and other robes similar to the High Priest in Revelation 17:4, in the description of the great prostitute.  This suggests that this great prostitute is somehow a false high priestess.
- A similar list of gems (in a different order) appears as the foundation stones in the description of the New Jerusalem in Revelation 21:19, 20 suggesting that, if the High Priest represented the High Priestly ministry of Jesus(1 Peter 2:5-9, Hebrews 4:14-16), this suggests that the New Jerusalem is founded on Jesus as our High Priest.

I could find no Biblical account of the significance of the choice of any individual gem.

Answer (score -1):

[Here is an encyclopedic collection](http://http//jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/6574-gems) of what we know about gems in the ancient world and in particular in the scriptures including a breakdown of what the gems mentioned in regard to the breastplate of the high priest and the foundation stones and such based on similar descriptions of gems from Arabic sources and such from the time.